# How to get events starting with current time in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to get events from starting with current time in fullcalendar v5.

Here's my calendar.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'list',
        views: {
            list: {
                type: 'listDay',
                duration: { days: 10 },
            },
        },
        eventSources: [{
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/calendar/get_all',
            extraParams: {
                teamMemberId
            }
        }],
        ...
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

In my code, the calendar has set the view mode as list of days.

But the option lets the calendar get events from the start of the day like 2021-03-01T00:00-07:00.

I want get events which the starting time is now.

Then how to do that or how to handle start params for the `eventSources` so I can set the starting time manually?

Comment: Why not just handle that in the server side code? It can read whatever start time it receives and adjust it to the current time. Might be a bit confusing for users though if they're expecting a list of the whole day's events. What you're proposing somewhat goes against the way that most people expect calendars to work. You might get some complaints about "missing" events, potentially.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of is to call `calendar.getEvents()` function where calendar is the reference to your fullcalendar object. Then just loop over the events and get the events which is greater than now. You can use properties `start` and `end` inside each event when you loop, they return javascript plain date object.